# Echo odd number and print next even number using awk and preventing results such as 1.00001e+06

Tags: ksh, hp-ux

I had a solution on AIX 7.1 where I could echo an odd number and print the next even number for example the below:

```
$ echo "3" | bc -l | awk '{printf("%.0f\n", $1)}' | awk '{$0=int($0/4+.75)*4}1'
4

$ echo "9" | bc -l | awk '{printf("%.0f\n", $1)}' | awk '{$0=int($0/4+.75)*4}1'
12
```

The problem I am facing is when the number reaches over a million, it starts giving me values such as below:

```
$ echo "1000009" | bc -l | awk '{printf("%.0f\n", $1)}' | awk '{$0=int($0/4+.75)*4}1'
1.00001e+06
```

What I should get is 1000012. The next even number what it gives me is irrelevant. As long as it is an even number. I am not sure if this is a limitation in HP-UX B.11.31, which I am testing on.

Is there a way to avoid getting results such as this?

Comment: Is there a reason to why you jump through all those hoops, i.e. why you pipe through `bc` and convert to float?

Comment: The last snippet works fine in good ol' Ubuntu bash. In case people want to investigate ksh/HP-UX specific things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
N=1000009
echo "${N:-3} 3+4/4*p" | dc
```

## Output

```
1000012
```